# Android (Xamarin, Mono for Android) - Web service works in emulator, but not on device

Tags: android, service, xamarin.android, content-type, xamarin

I'm hopeful that what I'm missing is something basic; I created an XML web service, which I can successfully call using an Android emulator. However, when I deploy the application, the same web service (the method I've been testing literally returns "Hello world." It's the default web service that gets created by Visual Studio.) fails. The message is "Not supported Content-Type in the response: 'text/html; charset=utf-8.'"

I take this to mean that the response is not coming back in XML format, which would obviously be a problem. But why would it be different in the emulator vs over the air? It's the same program/service!

Regardless, if anyone knows a workaround for this, or can guess what I've done wrong, it'd be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for review? Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on. A few pointers: Make sure you have the INTERNET permission set in your manifest file for the app. Also, try to access the webservice using the browser on the device to see if it's accessible. Last, but not least, I suggest you add some log statements and print out the actual contents of the error. It usually gives a lot more information that way.